# How to check if two finite lines touches?

Tags: geometry

I have this case where I need to check three 3D segments:

First line (the one that going to check the other two):
$x= 61, y = 2, z= 0$ and $x=11, y=-51, z=143$

Second Line: $x=36, y=-28, z=71$ and $x=43, y=-35, z=53$

And lastly the third line: $x=36, y=-28, z=71$ and $x=31, y=-23, z=85$

I'm looking to check if the segments touch with each other, on this example the result should show that the first line touches the third one but not the second one.

In short, I want to check if the lines touch with each other without looking them as infinite segments just if the lines intersect inside the two endpoints of each line.

Comment: Pretend they’re infinite. Two infinite lines will touch in at most one place. Check what that place is, and then if it’s “inside” the desired finite-length regions.

Comment: that's the problem, in this case that can't happen, they have to check if the lines touch inside the two endpoints or it's not considered.

The end goal is to check what line, or better said what vertices actually intersects at some point to discriminate what vertices to add in a group of vertex. If they intersect outside of their endpoint limits this can do some problems with the logic I'm trying to apply here.

Comment: Then use Vercingetorix answer if my approach doesn’t work for your specific use case.

Comment: "Touch" sounds like you mean the endpoint of one lies somewhere along the other segment. If that's not what you mean, just use the word "intersect".

Answer (score 4):

Express each line in algebraic form first.

Easy way to do that is: if $a$ is one end and $b$ is the other, then the general equation for the line is $ta +  (1-t)b$ where $t \in [0, 1]$.

So now you have three lines $(61, 2, 0)t + (11, -51, 143)(1-t)$, $(36, -28, 71)s + (1-s)(43, -35, 53)$ and so on.

Now to find a possible intersection of the first two lines for instance, you simply equate both (which should give you three equations to solve for $s$ and $t$). If both $s, t$ exist and both $s,t \in [0, 1]$ then you have the intersection within the finite segment of the line.

Comment: when you say "which should give you three equations to solve for s and t" you mean for example $t*ax +(1-t)*bx$ then $t*ay+(1-t)*by$ and so on? or you mean another thing?

Answer (score 0):

Given two lines in the form $\vec a_1+ \vec b_1t$ and $\vec a_2+ \vec b_2 t$, the shortest distance $d$ between the two lines is
$$d= \bigg| \frac{(\vec a_1-\vec a_2)\times(\vec b_1\times \vec b_2 )}{\vec b_1\times\vec b_2 }\bigg|$$
If any pair of lines touch each other, the their distance $d=0$. Thus, just check with the formula above.

Comment: This does not address OP’s concerns of whether the lines intersect within the given bounds.